# Possible duplicate question in another (programming) language

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168007/is-it-more-efficient-to-use-multiple-if-statements-or-one-with-lots-of-else-ifs) is about `if-if` statements vs `if-else if` statements in C#. And [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970275/performance-difference-of-if-if-vs-if-else-if) is asking the same thing, but in C/C++, which was answered perfectly, meanwhile the answer is also suitable for question1. Should the C# question be marked as a duplicate of the C/C++ even though they are different languages?

Comment: In my view, in general, different languages may have different features and restrictions to solve the problem, while 2 questions may have same answers occasionally, it does't imply they are asking or requiring the same thing. Also I see the question is about optimization, which is quite language specific, marking them as duplicate may mislead beginners.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd leave them separate, per language. If you can find a C# dupe, then use that one.

At first glance, the answers in the [current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168007/is-it-more-efficient-to-use-multiple-if-statements-or-one-with-lots-of-else-ifs) are similar to the [c/c++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970275/performance-difference-of-if-if-vs-if-else-if), which are also similar to this [java/c++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169249/why-we-use-if-else-if-instead-of-multiple-if-block-if-the-body-is-a-return-stat) and probably others too.

On the one hand, multiple `if` statements vs an `if/else` structure is a question about logic, and isn't necessarily dependent on a particular language, at least at first.

But then there's a comment like this in [the java/c++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169249/why-we-use-if-else-if-instead-of-multiple-if-block-if-the-body-is-a-return-stat), regarding whether there's any difference:

> It's a significant difference, because you can implement operator== in C++ to do nasty (side-effecty) things (which has also an influence on optimisation ...). AFAICR this doesn't work in Java.

If there are language-dependent considerations (like the above), based on the particular language the OP is asking about, they're not exact dupes.

Also, it may confuse/mislead people who are seeking answers about one language, to then be forwarded to a thread with examples and notes about a separate language.

Comment: TL;dr: it sets a bad precedent.